# What can one assume, what is worth assuming in Isar?

Tags: isabelle, isar

In Isar one uses `assume` with the premise of the goal so that she can use it building the conclusion.

The [Isabelle/Isar Reference](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#page=121)
says

```
assume expects to be able to unify with existing premises in the goal
```

Is this the only use of `assume`, namely, to get facts from the premises of the goal?

update: as some people consider this too broad, which I do not understand, I try to 
reformulate the question.

The manual describes the logical content of `assume`. But what is its usage? Is that confined to only the case when I get a fact from the premises of the goal?

Comment: You can also use "assume" in a local proof context (between "{" and "}"). Is it an exemple of what you want to know ?

Comment: Yes this is an example. I guess in a local proof context one can use `assume` for a premise.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? At the moment it is hard for me to say what it is you want to know. It should also be avoided to ask too broad a question or one whose answers are primarily opinion-based on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two uses of the `assume` keyword that are of course two instances of the same process: stating the premises of a property to be proved.

If we take a silly example:

```
lemma "∀A B C D. A ⟶ B ⟶ C ⟶ D ⟶ (A ∧ B) ∧ (C ∧ D)"
using assms
proof (intro allI impI)
  fix A B C D
  assume A B
  then have "A ∧ B" .. (* or "by rule", "by default", "by simp", ... *)

  { fix E F
    assume E and F
    then have "E ∧ F" ..
  } note H = this

  assume C D then have "C ∧ D" ..
  from H[OF `A ∧ B` `C ∧ D`] show "(A ∧ B) ∧ (C ∧ D)" . (* or "by fact" *)
qed
```

- either `assume` appears to state the premises generated by a `proof` command anywhere between  `proof` and `show` or `thus`. These assumed properties will have to be a subset of the premises generated by the `proof` command (here `A` `B` `C` and `D`).
- or `assume` appears in a block delimited by `{` and `}` where you can assume anything you want and then prove a property `P` stated with `have`. When the block is closed, a local fact is produced composed of the assumptions as premises, and the property `P` as a conclusion. In the example, I name it `H` and use it to prove the last conjunction.